# Create nuget containing shared project properties - automatic references

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, csproj

We would like to create a nuget that contains an msbuild properties (.props) file.  We do this by creating a nuspec which as the following MIL (most important line) :

```
  <files>
    <file src="SharedProperties.props" target="build\SharedProperties.props" />
  </files>
```

How can we change our .nuspec definition so that a project (.csproj) that references this nuget will automatically include the property file ("like" line 3 in this snippet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <Import Project="..\Shared\SharedProperties.props" />
```

(Is this even possible ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a feature of the nuget package design. And nuget has the automatic import targets mechanism. See [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package).

The tip is that you should name the targets or props file to <package_id>.props or targets and then pack the file into build folder. That is all.

For an example, I created a lib project and then use this nuspec file to pack:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>test_A</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>me</title>
    <authors>me</authors>
      ......
  </metadata>
<files>
<file src="test_A.props" target="build" />
</files>
</package>
```

If my package is called `test_A.1.0.0.nupkg`, the file should be named as `test_A.props` file.

**Then**, when you install the nuget package into a new project, you can check the `<new project>.csproj` file, the props file is added automatically during the nuget installation.

[image]

If you use PackageReference nuget management format to install the nuget package, the file is added under `obj\xxx.csproj.nuget.g.props` or `obj\xxx.csproj.nuget.g.targets` file:

[image]

For new-sdk project, that also work. If you create a new-sdk class library project, you could use this into csproj file to pack it:

```
<None Include="<packages_id>.props" Pack="true" PackagePath="build">
```

When you finish it, install the new package into new-sdk main project, you will find that the props file has imported automatically under `obj\xxx.csproj.nuget.g.props` file.

Comment: I finally got it to work.  I splitted my "props" file into 2 scripts.  The first defines the path to the rest.  And then I manually add an "imports" line to the csproj that uses the nuget (this is the part I still don't like but it does work).  This allows me to keep the imports line version independent.  I was also inspired by the https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSBuild.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.targets/ nuget.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package) the ".props" file should be automatically added to the beginning of a .csproj as an import (a  .targets file should go to the end).  However, for the new sdk-style projects this doesn't seem to work?

Comment: that is also work for new-sdk project. you could have a try.

Comment: you could use this `<None Include="<packages_id>.props" Pack="true" PackagePath="build">` under csproj file. And then right-click on the project Properties-->Pack to generate the nupkg(this is for new-sdk class library project). After you install this new  package into a new-sdk project, the props file will be imported under `obj\xxx.csproj.nuget.g.props` file when you install it..